# Subset of a data set

Tags: r, subset

The question relates to iris data set:

```
library(datasets)
data(iris)
```

How to extract column 'Sepal.Width' for the species virginica?

Comment: `subset(iris, Species=='virginica', select='Sepal.Width')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way:

```
iris$Sepal.Width[ iris$Species %in% "virginica"]
```

Probably best to google subsetting though as this is all easily available in tutorials everywhere, and this will have been asked elsewhere on SO.